# Can't port forward when usb0 is connected

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I connect my android phone to the Pi using USB and turn on the tethering. Everything runs smooth, I can `ssh` to the Pi using the phone and it's address (usb0 - 192.168.42.xxx). After, that I connect the Pi to my WiFi network and test the `ssh` connection again (wlan0 - 192.168.88.xxx), and again everything runs smooth.

The problem is that I can't port forward it when it is connected using the USB. When I tried to connect from a different network, it just timed me out. So, I unplugged the USB cable and after that I can `ssh` to the Pi. How can I make it run on all the addresses (usb0 (phone network), wlan0 (WiFi network) and the port forwarded WiFi (my IP address))?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is your network mask setting you see when you run `ifconfig`? If your network mask is set as `Mask:255.255.255.0`, your phone and wifi are basically on two different networks, you can either change the mask to `Mask:255.255.0.0` or set the IP address of both your phone and wifi to be within the same range `192.168.88.xxx`.